# How does lazy evaluation binds variable (in R)

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and I just noticed that the first call to a function seems to bind its environment parameters. How does this work ? (Or how is it it called, so I can look it up in the doc).

E.g.:

```
make.power <- function(n)
{
        pow <- function(x)
        {
                x^n
        }
}

i <- 3
cube <- make.power(i)
# print(cube(3)) # uncommenting this line change the value below

i <- 2
square <- make.power(i)

print(cube(3)) # this value changes depending on whether cube(3) was called before.
print(square(3))
```

I'm looking for a sample explanation of what's going on, or just the name of this feature, so I can look it up.

Thanks !

Comment: Not what you're asking, but you can prevent this "feature" by calling `force(n)` inside your `make.power()` function, before the `pow` defintion. Variables aren't evaluated until they are needed. The force will make sure you capture the value that's being passed to the function.

Comment: You can check out [argument evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation) in the R language Manual. Specifically search for information about "promises" in R. Also read about lazy evaluation in [Hadley's Advanced R Function chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).